# Forecasting a ARIMA(1,1,1) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima

ARIMA(1,1,1) process with constant term $\mu$ is
$X_t=\alpha X_{t-1}+\mu+Z_t+\beta Z_{t-1}$ where $Z_t$ is white noise with mean zero variance $\sigma ^2$.
Find one step and two step ahead forecast and show that $l$ step ahead forecast is $\alpha \hat X_t(l-1)+\mu$.

Here's what I did:

$X_{t+1}=\mu+\alpha X_T+Z_{t+1}+\beta Z_t$.
$\hat X_{t+1}=\mu +\hat \alpha X_t+\hat \beta \hat Z_t$
Similarly  $\hat X_{t+2}=\mu +\hat \alpha \hat X_{t+1}$.

Then I tried to prove $\alpha \hat X_t(l-1)+\mu$ using induction but the one step ahead and two step ahead doesn't satisfy the expression.
Are my one and two step ahead forecasts wrong?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add a `self-study` tag.

Comment: @RichardHardy Its already added. And this is not a homework question. It was just a problem that I found out when I was going through some past notes